# Can we register for iOS developer program from India

Tags: ios

Can we register for iOS developer program from India and sell the apps? In Google Play for Android I can not sell apps from India. So is it possible for iOS? and can I pay $99/year by VISA Debit card?
Sorry I searched everywhere but cant find the answer, even if this is not a 100% programming question but still please do answer if you can.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but no online registration support for India, you need to fax form to Apple. Last april I did same. Yes its 99 USD. You need credit card.

You can get iOS developer certificate here. [CLICK HERE](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)

In this link, click on Enroll Now button and continue till you get fax form from apple and follow their guidelines and send fax to apple.(They suggest all)

**UPDATES :** Now a days apple support online purchase for India also...no need to fax now..its are all in online mode now.

Comment: Thanx, so i have to fax the form, i din not knew that. And wont a Debit card help?

Comment: @user1527288, I used Credit Card, one more thing is your apple account name must match Credit card name, otherwise apple reject.

Comment: Thanx Raj, well my debit card is in my name, but i dont have a credit card, will try to do it with debit card and see what happens.

Comment: Welcome and try with Credit card. All the Best.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2012-03-06/computing/31126609_1_app-stores-google-s-android-market-app-developer) you can join iOS developer program and you can sell your apps on the App Store. If this information is not enough for you, you can [contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and ask them. Good luck!